# Have the Retina MacBook Pro GPU Hangs been fixed?

Tags: macos, crash, performance, gpu

I have an early 2013 15-inch retina Macbook Pro running the latest stable version of Yosemite on which I've encountered the fabled GPU hang-ups, detailed in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150961/complete-system-hang-graphics-card-related-intelaccelerator-bad-busy-count). I'm almost certain I have the same issue as described; I see similar messages on the console, and it seems to only happen when I open an intensive app like photoshop, thus causing the computer to switch between graphics devices.

In the way of possible fixes, I understand that one can disable graphics switching, but that decreases battery life, which I'd like to avoid. However, I haven't seen the issue in a few weeks anyway, which makes me wonder if it hasn't been fixed. The app store doesn't show any major system updates in the past 30 days. Was there an update I didn't notice that fixed this issue?

Comment: If you are on 10.10.2 and it is still there, than it was not fixed. Waiting for 10.10.3 to see if it fixes it or get it to check.

Answer (score 1):

Bring it into your nearest Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Provider and they can run a VST (AST Video System Test). That specific MBPr model is eligible for a repair program right now, so you'll get a free Logic Board replacement if it fails the VST test. Here is the [Apple Support page](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) with the information.